# How find square root n by computing the next Xi term on javascript

Tags: javascript, sqrt

Write the function sqrt(A) for computing square root of positive real numbers using next numerical method xi+1 = (1/2) * (xi +(A/xi)). Where the A - input rial number;
On zero iteration next statements have been taken: x0 = A;
The error should be at least 10^-6

Comment: What is the question what is the code? Math.sqrt(Math.pow(n,11));

Comment: Its your HOMEWORK so at-least try something and its already there [`Math.sqrt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt).

Comment: image with task not loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the last value x<sub>i-1</sub> and compare it with the new value x<sub>i</sub> instead of using a loop counter.

```js
function sqrt(a, x = 1) {    // take 1 for x(0) as start value for recursion
    var y = (x + a / x) / 2; // prepare next value x(i+1)

    if (x === y) {           // exit condition
        return x;
    }
    return sqrt(a, y);       // tail call optimization 
}                            // https://stackoverflow.com/q/310974/1447675

console.log(sqrt(2));
console.log(sqrt(10));
console.log(sqrt(9));
console.log(sqrt(25));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your requirement is not just finding the square root of a number. If by any chance that is your requirement, use Math.sqrt.

If your requirement is to implement a function to find the square root for educational purpose, what you need is to write a recursive function as below. Modify the code as required to support error at 10^-6

```js
function sqrt(A, i = 0) {
  if (i === 0)
    return A;

  let prev = sqrt(A, i - 1);
  return 0.5 * (prev + (A / prev));
}

console.log(sqrt(2,1000));
console.log(sqrt(3,1000));
console.log(sqrt(9,1000));
console.log(sqrt(25,1000));
```